# How to handle null reference in asp.net Repeater item with foreign-key relations

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm having trouble with null reference in asp.net repeater control.
The repeater iterates through an `IEnumerable<T>` of a class with referenced properties.
I have the following classes:

```
public class SubTarget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ModelId { get; set; }

    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Model()
    {
        SubTargetTypes = new HashSet<SubTargetType>();
    }
}
```

And repeater control:

```
<asp:Repeater
    runat="server" ItemType="SubTarget" SelectMethod="GetSubTargets">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Item.SubTargetType.Name %></td>
                    <td><%# Item.Model.Name %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The problem is: `Model` property on `SubTarget`is optional. So when `ModelId`is null, the references to properties on `Model` obviously can't be found.
The repeater control correctly handles the null `ModelId` when called with just `<%# Item.Model %>` and leaves the space empty, but when calling `<%# Item.Model.Name %>` I get a null reference exception.

Any ideas how to display just blank space when Foreign key is not set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 <td><%# Item.Model !=null ? Item.Model.Name : string.Empty %></td>
```

I hope help you. :)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. I should have known that tho :D